# If many Laravel 4 queries for my application will need to be DB::raw, then what advantages are there in using Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel, laravel-4

I'm not a fan of ORMs. The great SO contributor Bill Karwin's thoughts represent my feelings fairly well. See **[here](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2008/05/activerecord-does-not-suck.html)** and **[here](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-should-you-use-orm.html)** (*and read his **[specific responses on Glenn Block's list of advantages of an ORM](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-should-you-use-orm.html)***).

I think just using good solid SQL in a repository pattern or/and DAL is the best approach for creating an app that will do more than just the small examples (with simple databases) I see in tutorial after tutorial. (and I never want to see another `Posts::model()->findAll();` example please!). It seems all the energy is spent on how to do a cool one-liner, instead of real scenario after scenario. Try complex joins, self joins, heavy aliasing, concatenation, nested or's/ands, aggregate functions on results or in sorting, sub-queries, composite keys, table prefixes, and you start to get my point.

However I know they have become better over the years and I like Laravel 4 so much that I figured I finally need to give them another try. But after evaluating my needs, it appears many of my queries will need to be ran **"raw"**`DB::select(DB::raw` because Eloquent can't handle them properly or it becomes more complex to express it as opposed to using SQL directly.

**What are the advantages to using Eloquent/Query Builder when many of the queries must be ran "raw", as opposed to using SQL purely and adding any methods in the repository or DAL to cover for all your data access needs?** Because it seems to me that raw queries in Laravel are the same as pure SQL and I don't get any of the advantages the ORM offers in those situations. I would be forced to create my own methods for things I'd be already using in the ORM like accessors, mutators, timestamps, soft deleting, etc for those `DB::raw` situations. Also the advantage of swapping out database engines compatible with Eloquent would be lost.

Comment: Few reasons, easily readable, maintainable and will not be the nightmare for new comers.

Comment: That can and SHOULD be the case for someone who is writing direct SQL. They should adhere to readable, maintable code. And what newcomers are hired that are going to be more familiar with the ORM then the SQL that the ORM is based upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just ramping up on laravel, but here are my thoughts...

I view the strength in an ORM is in substituting it in lieu of executing raw sql queries. My feeling is that if you are already having to write raw sql queries, shelf the ORM and do it all yourself. It's likely the model is complex enough that you'll run into efficiency problems long term anyway.

The second issue that comes to mind is the context switching between using the ORM and the raw queries. Karwin, in his blog posts, mentions that most people use ORMs "inexpertly". My guess is that if you are using it for very light data access/queries you won't develop a deep understanding of it and will fall into that category. ORMs can be very complex and it's tough to get a good feel for how to use them appropriately.

**Note:** To date, I've not found an ORM that I liked enough to implement on a wide scale, but I've got a simple project that I'm going to try and use one with as I work with Laravel.

Comment: For me...a certain example situation where ORMs are used "inexpertly" is when several queries are fired off and greatly increase the query count of a page. This can be a built in flaw with the ORM itself, and using it "inexpertly" in this case means you are using it when you SHOULDN'T. Plus people are going to be less inclined to take the time to copy the query outputted by the ORM and run EXPLAIN on it or try to optimize it. If the foundational tutorials out there are not using ORM's in a "heavy" way, then this is partly to blame.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris. I'll probably accept it, if no one else chime's in here soon. It confirms what I feared already I think. I hate losing such a big part of a framework I really like.

Comment: I think that's a great thought. It makes me think that using an ORM may result in the developer not even realizing how many or when queries are generated. He/she is surprised when the DB takes a thrashing as a result. With raw SQL you know exactly when you are running queries because you wrote the query yourself. The whole ORM issue has driven me to use the SLIM framework more and more since it does some of the things I want without the heavy framework. It's light on "magic" for sure.

Comment: Haven't heard of SLIM. Will have to check it out. The **package management** (using composer and such) and the **routing** in Laravel are so nice.

Comment: http://www.slimframework.com/ It's got routing and some other basic features, but is very lightweight.

Comment: Is the community pretty active on SLIM? (I noticed your from San Antone, so I said "pretty" in my Texan draw, as I'm in Austin and from West Texas. :-)

Comment: Not implementing composer/Packagist might be the deal breaker for me on this framework though.

Comment: Upvoted you. But I'm looking for someone to respond with more of what they do in this "mixed" situation. Such as: Is the inconsistency worth it? Does it make sense to use built-in Laravel methods for half of the queries and then write your own version of those same methods for the other half? You say abandon it completely, but surely this can't be the case with all Laravel devs? I agree with what you are saying, but I hope I don't end up dropping the ORM completely! LOL! Maybe I use it just to stay fresh with it.

Comment: How do they compensate for not having some of the Eloquent advantages when they write a DB::raw query. Is there something I'm missing? IE. you have to manually perform what you would perform in the mutator?

Comment: The nice thing is that the community can be smaller when the framework does less. There isn't a need for constant development. I am indeed in SATX.